# recommended css notation

Tags: css

I have a div with an ID:

```
<div id="main">
```

What's the correct (or difference) between

```
div#main {
```

and

```
#main {
```

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a great doco](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering#UseEfficientCSSSelectors) on using efficient CSS selectors, focus on *rules with overly qualified selectors*:

> ID selectors are unique by definition. Including tag or class
>   qualifiers just adds redundant information that needs to be evaluated
>   needlessly.

Instead of just applying the style to an element with id `main`, your selector will re-qualify the element by checking whether or not it's also a `div` (in that order). To clarify: css selectors are evaluated *right to left*, unlike same selector syntax when used in jQuery etc.

Re pixelistik's suggestion that `div#main` is more specific than `#main` - yes, that is technically correct, however if you have to resort to this to raise a rule's specificity, chances are the structure of CSS you're working on is not as thought through as it should be.

Answer (score 2):

So difference is that:

When you write `div#main` style will be only for `<div>` element.
When you write `#main` it can be used as style for `<div>`,  `<span>`, `<p>`, etc.

And what recommend is hard to say, every developer it has it different. So i using for example 
`span.<nameClass>` when is nested in `<li>` for example.

```
#nav li span.href a {
 ...
}
```

I think it's used when you want that someone class with specific name can have only one element.

So when your write `span#href` it will works only for `<span id="href">Simply dummy text</span>` not for others. When you write `#href` it will works for `<span id="href">Simply dummy text</span>` or `<a href="#" id="href">Link</a>` but both are correct when you also asking about this. Differences i wrote above.

Comment: I can't think of a scenario when the same `id` could/should be applied to different elements. Even if this is not specified in the selector, you *know* what element you're targeting

Comment: @o.v.: It can be applied to different elements in non-conforming markup, in which case `#main` will target all of them. But, you know, nobody likes non-conforming HTML :)

Comment: men, i know what are you talking about, author of this topic asked us to say differences between #main and div#main. So im not using this, maybe little a few times but i don't creating different elements with same class.

Comment: @BoltClock: Ah, for some reason I was thinking of an awkward scenario when `id="main"` could be applied to either a div or a table etc., but still *one id per document*. I'm sure if same ID is applied to multiple elements on the page, CSS performance would be the least of your worries :)

Answer (score 2):

`#main` matches everything with ID 'main', whereas `div#main` matches only `<div>` elements with ID main.

Ideally, you should never have two elements with the same ID, so realistically the two don't make a difference, but there's probably performance related issues regarding whether specifying `div` makes it find the result faster.

Comment: Makes it slower actually. As I said in my answer below, css selectors are parsed RTL, meaning that upon finding an element with an id `main`, the rendering engine will have to check whether or not it's also a `div`. While the effort around this could be seen as negligible, I'd worry more about the structural impact and possibly unwanted specificity override.

Comment: @o.v. That an element's type is checked after a browser finds it by its ID has nothing to do with RTL parsing. RTL parsing works across combinators.

Comment: @BoltClock: consider two scenarios, when a `#aaa .bbb` is evaluated by the rendering engine and when it is used to match DOM elements w/JS. In the first scenario, all elements matching `.bbb` will be found first, and then re-qualified by looking up their parent (RTL). In the second scenario, an element matching `#aaa` is (quickly) found and then its descendants are searched for a match against `.bbb`. This is what I meant by saying *css selectors are parsed RTL* - two polarly different ways to solve the same problem. And I don't know why, I just go with the flow :)

Comment: @o.v.: That's exactly what I mean by "across combinators". In your example, you have two component selectors, `#aaa` and `.bbb`. Naturally, the key selector is `.bbb`, so browsers will find that first and then check if it's in an `#aaa`. But in the question, there's only one: `div#main`. Most browsers do look up a `#main` element and then check if it's a `div`, but that has nothing to do with RTL parsing.

Comment: @BoltClock: well, TIL. Does your comment imply that `#aaa.bbb` and `.bbb#aaa` selectors would be both evaluated the same way i.e. order of lookup etc.?

Comment: @o.v.: Maybe... I can't say for sure since I don't know the implementation details, but I'm sure the RTL stuff doesn't go so deep.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

`div#main` is more specific than `#main`, which means that styles defined with the first selector will override the ones of the second.

Here's a good introduction to CSS specifity:
http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/